# How to migrate hyperloglog key to azure redis

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache, hyperloglog

I am trying to migrate an redis hyperloglog key from one server to azure redis service using the [MIGRATE](http://redis.io/commands/MIGRATE) command, but as far as i know [MIGRATE doesn't support moving key to a redis server which requires authentication](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/2507).

How can i migrate hyperlolog key then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code it on any client, an HyperLogLog is just a string. You can probably GET the string on the source server and SET on the destination.

```
x = Server1.StringGet(key);
Server2.StringSet(key, x);
```

[image: redis-cli example]